# wxColour set with int array?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to pass an array to a wxColour element:

```
    int COLOUR_DEFAULT [4] = {0, 0, 100, 255};
    myelement->SetBackgroundColour(*COLOUR_DEFAULT);
```

But it does not work.

If I do:

```
    #define  COLOUR_DEFAULT         {100, 100, 100, 255}
    myelement->SetBackgroundColour(COLOUR_DEFAULT);
```

….it works. How can I make it work with the variable?

Comment: Independently of your (already answered) main question, consider using `wxALPHA_OPAQUE` instead of 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WxWidgets, if you want to make a WxColour class, you must define the variable as

`wxColour COLOUR_DEFAULT(0, 0, 100, 255);`

You can not pass an integer array directly to a function expecting a WxColour parameter.

Now you can simply type the following (it is no longer a pointer, so the `*` is not needed):

`myelement->SetBackgroundColour(COLOUR_DEFAULT);`

Comment: So I made:

        wxColour COLOUR_DEFAULT = {0, 0, 100, 255};
        myelement->SetBackgroundColour(COLOUR_DEFAULT);


And it works!
Thank you very much!